# Does GlobalScope.launch create a new thread or run in the same thread?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have the question from this code.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html

```
fun main() {
    GlobalScope.launch { // launch new coroutine in background and continue
        delay(1000L) // non-blocking delay for 1 second (default time unit is ms)
        println("World!") // print after delay
    }
    println("Hello,") // main thread continues while coroutine is delayed
    Thread.sleep(2000L) // block main thread for 2 seconds to keep JVM alive
}
```

I replace delay(1000L) with Thread.sleep(1000L). If GlobalScope.launch block will run in the same thread, the Thread.sleep(1000L) will block the thread. However it seems not.

```
fun main() {
    GlobalScope.launch { // launch new coroutine in background and continue
        Thread.sleep(1000L)
        println("World!")
    }
    println("Hello,") // 
    Thread.sleep(2000L) // block main thread for 2 seconds to keep JVM alive
}
```

Comment: Found it. In the 2 examples, GlobalScope.launch runs in a different thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GlobalScope` lets you start coroutines which more-or-less have the same behavior as [daemon threads](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/docs/basics.md#global-coroutines-are-like-daemon-threads) since they are detached from any Coroutine-`Job` and basically run as long as the application. Their lifecycle is only limited by the application itself. This is something you want to avoid by using "[structured concurrency](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/docs/basics.md#structured-concurrency)" which basically means that your coroutines should be nested in a way that you can control them without manually keeping track of their references and joining them for example in order to await their computations. So in your real-life code you should avoid `GlobalScope` as much as possible, since there's most certainly a better solution.

As to your question, and as already mentioned, the `GlobalScope` runs on the `Dispatchers.Default` pool, which means that you will block *some worker thread* but not the one you spawned the coroutine from.

On the other hand, if you were to write this block:

```
fun main() {
    runBlocking { 
        Thread.sleep(1000L) 
        println("World!") 
    }
    println("Hello,") 
    Thread.sleep(2000L) 
}
```

you'll see that the coroutine blocks the `main` thread and the output will show a different result. That is because `runBlocking` runs on the caller thread `main` rather than one of the worker pool threads.

Answer (score 1):

`GlobalScope.launch { }` will not necessarily *create* a new thread, but it will use one from a shared pool because it uses the `Default` dispatcher. So, as far as your question is concerned, in your snippet, the block passed to launch runs in a different thread indeed.

In the documentation about [dispatchers and threads](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#dispatchers-and-threads), you will find the following:

> The default dispatcher, that is used when coroutines are launched in GlobalScope, is represented by Dispatchers.Default and uses shared background pool of threads

And in the [Dispatchers.Default doc](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-default.html), you can find:

> By default, the maximal level of parallelism used by this dispatcher is equal to the number of CPU cores, but is at least two. Level of parallelism X guarantees that no more than X tasks can be executed in this dispatcher in parallel.

Note that you could change the dispatcher by providing one as a parameter of `launch`.

Comment: "but it will use one from a shared pool". Do you imply GlobalScope.launch { } runs in another thread, if the CPU has at least 2 cores?

Comment: Not really. In fact, the pool contains at least 2 threads, even for single code processors. That what the doc states if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The `GlobalScope.launch{..}` function will not block. It returns an `Job` object, which you may use to wait for a result.

Behind the scenes, the `GlobalScope` uses the default dispatcher `Dispatchers.Default`. You may see it, for example, by printing a thread name inside a `launch{..}` function.

You will need to run more coroutines to see them blocking each other because of `Thread.sleep` calls.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html